# Magento image media custom attribute - Not showing url

Tags: magento

I'm having trouble in getting magento to echo the url of a custom attribute that I have created for magento's custom attribute set.

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product->load($_selection->getProductId());
echo $_product->getCustomimage();
```

in admin, the attribute code is customimage which load Image Media.

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of that attribute? If it's only text and its name is «customimage» and not «custom_image», the way you're calling it seems to be OK. Is that the code you're using?

Maybe you should load the product in a variable and then call that method in order to get the url of that image. Try loading a specific product to see if it works...

```
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
  echo $product->getCustomimage();
```

You can take a look [at this](http://www.devinrolsen.com/magento-custom-attributes-value).